# What EXACTLY do I do to remotely access my server from SSH?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm having way too much trouble getting remote tunneling to work. Mainly, just what I need to type into the terminal to get it to work. I understand this is probably a duplicate, but at least that will get me pointed in the right direction.

Here is what I did so far:

1) I went into my Xfinity gateway page and turned on port forwarding.
2) I added both the IPv4 and IPv6 address of my server into the port forwarding setup dialog, along with port 22 for my listening port, whatever that means. 
Here is where I am stuck:

**What do I write in my terminal to access my server!**

Do I write

```
"ssh username@Router_IP_Address" or "ssh -R (some random thing about port 
22):localhost:(port 22 again for some reason) username@server_ip"
```

I have been looking for an answer for way too long, and I just need an answer. I have spent 4 years on Ubuntu, and never any problems. This one has been going on for 3 days. Please help me.

Comment: Hold on, are you trying to bind a port of your remote machine to your local machine, for example port 80 so you can access a site via localhost:80? or are you just trying to ssh remotly to a server? Question is kinda unclear in that regard.

Comment: Have you tried the options you mentioned? What was the result in each case?

Comment: I have tried all of them, and the only way that i could ssh into my server was if i was on my local network. then, i just used `ssh <user>@<server_IP>`

Comment: Oh, so your configuration on your router is incorrect. You're probably not forwarding correctly. What IP address are you using to try connecting remotly the WAN address from your router right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want to connect to your home machine (port-forwarded through your home router) over the internet.

The syntax for this would be (if 123.456.789.00 is your home ip address):

```
ssh user@123.456.789.00
```

Or if you have a domain name:

```
ssh user@yourdomainname.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified clearly what you are trying to do.

1. Is it a remote server somewhere on internet that you want to ssh into?
2. Is it a Local server that you are trying to ssh into?
3. Is your computer the server and you are trying to login into your computer from the internet?

If it is first or second case than you don't need port forwarding and the command you would run in these cases is,

```
ssh <username>@<server address>
```

By default, It assumes that the port is 22. If it is not 22 than you need to run this command.

```
ssh <username>@<server address> -p <port number>
```

If it is the third case, Then, First of all, You need to start a ssh server on your computer. On Ubuntu you can do, `sudo service sshd start`
to start a ssh server. Now, Setup port forwarding correctly, And in short, If someone sends a request to your public IP address on port 22(or on which ever port you setup port forwarding) It should send that request to your local server on which ssh server is running.

Once it is done, You should be able to access your local computer from the internet by running this command.

```
ssh <your pc's username>@<Your public IP address> -p <Port that you used in port forwarding>
```

let me know if any of this sounds confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll clarify because I tried your method before, and I was having trouble. I have Dell PE 1950 server set up in my boiler room at home. I spend most of my day away from home but connected to the internet. in the past, I could ssh into my server just by the command "ssh <user>@<IP address that comes up in system settings/networking>" but that was only on my home wifi. When I tried that on my work wifi, it didn't work. I will try this again, but it looks like your option 1. I'll let you know if I figure it out and how. Thanks!

Comment: More likely to be option 3, because it is your computer at home that you want to ssh into. You'll most likely need to setup port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are trying to tunnel one port via ssh you only need to use this command. It will use the port 22 of your router.

> ssh [user]@[remoteMachine-ipaddress] -L [localMachinePort]:localhost:[remoteMachinePort]

e.g.

> ssh test@10.10.10.10 -L 10000:localhost:80

Now the website of 10.10.10.10:80 is available on your localhost on port 10000 via encrypted connection of port 22.